# Transition not working in IE and Edge and Safari

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I got problems trying to add a transition for a transform in IE, Edge and on mobile Safari. There is a element which get transformed with another class which get added with jQuery.
The css of the full height element looks follows:

```
.post-hero {
   height: calc(100% - 178px);
   width: 100%;
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   padding: 0 25px;
   margin-top: 128px;
   transition: (1.2s, all, cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.44, 0, 1));
}
```

And this classes get added on a click event

```
.up {
   transform: translateY(-100%) translateY(88px);
}

.down {
  transform: translateY(+100%) translateY(88px);
}
```

The transform works well in Firefox and Chrome. But the other browser should support it as well (http://caniuse.com/#search=transition)

**Edit**

It's all about the syntax. `transition: (1.2s, all, cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.44, 0, 1));` is no valid CSS. Should be `transition: 1.2s all cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.44, 0, 1);`

Comment: `transition: (1.2s, all, cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.44, 0, 1));` should really be `transition: all 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.44, 0, 1);` For the shorthand property you separate the different transition-properties using spaces, not commas, and you don't wrap them in brackets.

Comment: Furthermore, you have `transform: translateY(-100%) translateY(88px);` defining two different translations for the same `translateY` property. You sure that's what you wanted?

Comment: `transform: translateY(-100%) translateY(88px); ` is wanted because IE can't calculate inside translateY, but was the syntax as you described above.

Comment: For the translate css i use all the prefixes as follows: `-webkit-transform: ..., -moz-transform:..., -ms-transform:..., -o-transform:..., transform:....` maybe this helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned above it's a combination of the lacking meta tag: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` and the false CSS syntax for the transition `transition: (1.2s, all, cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.44, 0, 1));` which should be declared in this way: `transition: 1.2s all cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.44, 0, 1);`